# PrimeNG Accordion: Gets open on second time opening inside dialog or overlay

Tags: accordion, primeng

I have following code:

```
<button pButton type="text" label="Show Overlay" (click)="op.toggle($event)"><\/button>
<p-overlayPanel #op>
   <p-accordion multiple="true">
      <p-accordionTab header="Header 1">Content 1<\/p-accordionTab>
      <p-accordionTab header="Header 2">Content 2<\/p-accordionTab>
   <\/p-accordion>
<\/p-overlayPanel>
```

After page load, When I click first time on button overlay open as expected, but the problem is when click second time accordion gets expanded (content visible but shows collapse icons).

Angular version - 7.x.x
Primeng version- 7.x.x

Comment: <button pButton type="text" label="Show Overlay" (click)="op.toggle($event)"></button>

<p-overlayPanel #op>
    <p-accordion multiple="true">
        <p-accordionTab header="Header 1">Content 1</p-accordionTab>
       <p-accordionTab header="Header 2">Content 2</p-accordionTab>
    </p-accordion>
</p-overlayPanel>
Code can be found here, in discription it was not getting appendent

Comment: Hi @Minal, do you have any solution... I didn't understand your reply..

Answer (score 0):

I faced same the issue. Its some bug in Angular / PrimeNG. This workaround from https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/9453 worked for me:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .p-accordion-tab:not(.p-accordion-tab-active) {
    .p-toggleable-content {
      height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  }

  .p-accordion-tab.p-accordion-tab-active {
    .p-toggleable-content {
      height: auto !important;
      overflow: auto !important;
    }
  }
}
```

In component hosting accordion just:

```
styleUrls: ['./some-name.component.scss']
```